# Entity Framework 5 failure while adding a new record of a specific object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

[image]I truly do not know how to solve this issue , i am used to add or remove object using entity framework in this way always . 
i run my app in debug mode and followed it . 
the debugger continue with no issues at all , then i look into database for a new record , but nothing happen at all .

```
 private dbClinics _context;
    public dbClinics context { get { return new dbClinics(); } set { _context = value; } }
    #endregion

    private void _AddProfession(string ProfessionName)
    {
        if (!context.Professions.Any(x => x.ProfessionName.ToLower().Equals(ProfessionName.ToLower())))
        {
            Profession profession = new Profession();
            profession.ProfessionName = ProfessionName;
            context.Professions.Add(profession);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Here is the connection string :

```
<add name="dbClinics" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ADO.dbClinics.csdl|res://*/ADO.dbClinics.ssdl|res://*/ADO.dbClinics.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mld\markinstance;initial catalog=beta_clinics;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

And Sure i have make sure that the table auto increment its primary key

[image]

Comment: somthing else is wrong, did you refresh database in sql server?

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi yes i did multiple times

Comment: add this line after savechange method and set break point after it:  var p1= context.Professions.Select(p=>p.ProfessionName ==ProfessionName);

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi i added .FirstOrDefault() it returns FALSE;

Comment: If you are not getting an exception close SSMS and reopen.  It may not be refresh.  If you still aren't getting the data then the connecton string is pointing to a different database.   The conneciton string in c# should match the login window in SSMS including the Server Name and Instance of the Database (Server Name\ Instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to your context property it recreates dbcontext for each call so the context you add the entity is not the same as the one you call save changes
Please manage dbcontext life cycle - preferably by using using statement